# How to load static data in local sqlite DB

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I have an small app created with xamarin.forms.

Now I want to get data for my created Tables from for example an Excel file, which is stored on an FTP Server.

Is this possilbe and how can I get this data into my local SQLite DB in the application on every start, so that always the newest data are available?

Creating my Table:

```
string dbpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "MyDatabase.db");
    var connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);            
    connection.CreateTable<MyTable>();
```

If the table is created, the table should be filled with the data from the excel file which is stored on a FTP Server.

Comment: Do you want to achieve the code like following sceenshot? https://imgur.com/a/LDTbGpt   Use static model in the `app.xaml.cs`

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT No this is not what I'm looking for... I know how to create database and table but I need to load data from an external file to my created table and also check if the data already exit

Comment: Can you share a simple path about external file?

Comment: Something like xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/MyFolder/DBDataFolder/dbdata.xls

Comment: 1. download the file, 2. open it with some Excel  library, 3. iterate through the data and update your local db.  There is nothing magical about this, you just have to do the work to make it happen.  Is there some specific part of this process you need help doing?

Comment: Can you please post an code snip how to do this?

Comment: No.  That is (at least) three different operations, and all of them are fairly well documented on SO and elsewhere on the web.  Please do some basic research on your own, and if you run into a **specific** problem that you need help with, feel free to ask a question about it.  Please read [ask] for guidance on writing good questions.